# How do I make my custom camera app the default one?

Tags: java, android

If I would use the following code:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,1);
```

it would start the default Android camera app right... I've written a custom camera app, but how do let Android know that it's a camera app, and that the user should be given the choice which Camera app to use.

In other words, if I used the code above, *my* app should start, and not the default android one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but how do let Android know that it's a camera app, and that the user should be given the chose which Camera app to use.

Have an `<intent-filter>` on an `<activity>` for that action:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

The next time that somebody executes your above `startActivityForResult()` call, you will appear in the chooser alongside anything else that supports that `Intent` structure.

Comment: It works! I knew it had someting to do with the intent-filter-tags, but didn't find the correct answer. Thanks!