# How to changing my app to be default camera app?

Tags: android, camera

If I developed a new camera app for live video, is there a way to force 3rd party apps that use the camera, for example periscope, to use my new camera app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make my custom camera app the default one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216908/how-do-i-make-my-custom-camera-app-the-default-one)

Answer (score 0):

No.

First, I would imagine that an app like Periscope works with the camera hardware directly, just as your proposed app would.

Second, even for apps that [use `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE) to delegate the video recording to a third-party app, it is the *user* who decides what app to use, not you.